# gradle: copy war to tomcat directory

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a Gradle task which copies generated war files to my local tomcat instance:

This isn't working and I'm not sure how to debug it:

```
 task deploylocal() << {
    println "Copy from ${buildDir}\\libs into ${tomcatHome}/webapps"
    copy{
      from "${buildDir}\\libs"
      into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
      include '*.war'
    }
  }
```

Any ideas on what to do next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you might be able to leverage the [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, I  might use that instead!

Answer (score 51):

The WAR task is aware of the artifacts it generates.

```
task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {
    from war.archivePath
    into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
}
```

Comment: [Ken](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1375187/ken) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/260494) that you would not have declare the `dependsOn: 'war'`: the fact that you are copying from `war.archivePath` is an implicit dependency.

Comment: I'd recommend using the `Copy` task type instead of the method call `copy`. The method call doesn't provide you with UP-TO-DATE checks.

Comment: I had my `war.dependsOn test` and I had to add `deployToTomcat.dependsOn war` to make sure my tests ran.

Answer (score 14):

I accomplished this with:

```
task deploy (dependsOn: war){
    copy {
        from "build/libs"
        into "C:/dev/jetty-distribution-9.1.4.v20140401/webapps"
        include "*.war"
    }
}
```

running it like this:

```
gradle deploy
```

Comment: This might copy multiple versions all at once (unless you clean often), it's better to copy only `war.archivePath` as suggested in other answers to copy latest version only.

Answer (score 12):

You could of-course use the tomcat plugin. My setup prevents me from using/modify the out of the box war & tomcat option.

I personally like the following flavor (copied from my build.gradle).

```
tomcat_home='tomcat_location'
tomcat_bin=tomcat_home + '/bin'
tomcat_start=tomcat_bin + '/startup.sh'
tomcat_stop=tomcat_bin + '/shutdown.sh'
tomcat_webapps = tomcat_home + '/webapps'

task tom << {
    if (project.hasProperty('start')) {
        startTom()
    } else if (project.hasProperty('stop')) {
        stopTom()
    } else if (project.hasProperty('deployNstart')) {
        stopTom()
        webappsCopy()
        startTom()
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('unrecognized option')
    }
}

def stopTom() {
    executeCmd(tomcat_stop)
}

def startTom() {
    executeCmd(tomcat_start)
}


def executeCmd(command) {
    proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
}

def webappsCopy() {
    copy {
        from 'war file location' // could be exploded or war itself
        into tomcat_webapps
    }
}
```

-- you call the various options you include in the 'tom' task from the command line --

```
$ gradle tom -Pstart
$ gradle tom -Pstop
$ gradle tom -PdeployNstart
```

this could potentially grow further, as I add more commands/options related to Tomcat. Few pointers:

1. move the location etc. to gradle.properties so that it could work
   in different environments.
2. poll your tomcat server port to fine tune
   options and msgs.
3. move to plugin/task code that could be reused.

this limited version works for me right now :-)

Answer (score 7):

You could give the [Gradle Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) a shot. It lets you deploy a WAR file to a local as well as a remote Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure the war archive is getting bundled before `deploylocal` is executed.
Maybe, you could define a dependency:

```
task deploylocal(dependsOn: build) << {
```

NB There is a convention property in java plugin named `libsDir`. It allows you to reference build/libs directory in better way:

```
 task deploylocal(dependsOn: build) << {
    println "Copy from ${libsDir.getPath()} into ${tomcatHome}/webapps"
    copy{
      from libsDir
      into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
      include '*.war'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually later a replaced this functionality with cargo plugin for gradle and runn the deploy by

```
gradle cargoRunLocal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the [war](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) plugin you can also just add

```
war.doLast {
    copy {
        from war.archiveFile
        into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
    }
}
```

Then you will always automatically deploy each time you build the war file.

Answer (score 0):

First, attempting to debug. Check the order of task execution; see if it it being run after the war file is produced. Also whether or not it says UP-TO-DATE.

The problem could be the lack of any dependencies between the this task and the output you want to copy.

Try replacing this general task with an instance of a Copy task, and make it dependent on the war file you're trying to copy.

Something like this:

```
task deployLocal(type: Copy) { 
    dependsOn configurations.archives.buildArtifacts
    from configurations.archives.allArtifacts*.file 
    into("$tomcatHome/webapps") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy the war in another local path, you can directly generate the war in the desired directory [using `destinationDirectory`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:destinationDirectory) property of the `war` plugin.

```
war {
   destinationDirectory = new File("${tomcatHome}/webapps")
}
```