# Run Gradle webapp in NetBeans'(8.0) tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, gradle

There's similar question: [gradle-copy-war-to-tomcat-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209847/gradle-copy-war-to-tomcat-directory) to use [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin).

Is it possible not to use that plugin, but use the NetBeans' default installed tomcat?

I want to just right click on the project, and select 'Run' to run the project just like that NetBeans Web Application runs in NetBeans' tomcat.

or should I switch to maven? Because it looks like more fit into NetBeans?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install core Gradle plugin for NetBeans (https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project) and its addition for Java EE projects - https://github.com/hildo/netbeans-gradle-javaee-project. Both are available from https://github.com/hildo/netbeans-gradle-javaee-project so you should see them in Plugin manager in your IDE.

Basic Gradle support works but I haven't tried the Java EE functionality so I cannot comment how much help you will get with deployment to Tomcat. You can create an action/shortcut to run a task in your Gradle build to deploy your application.

Comment: Why even post this if you don't know whether or not those two plugins actually do what the OP asks?

Comment: Because there is a variety of means how to achieve what was asked. Each have pros and cons and there is no complete answer to such open-ended question. As you can see there wasn't any other answer in two years because it is really uncharted territory.

Comment: There's a variety of ways to run a Gradle war on tomcat via Netbeans? Why do I not see an actual solution then? Any real solution will do. I tried setting it up similar to how IntelliJ manages deployments on tomcat and I kept hitting a dead end. The plugins you recommended were literally found the first couple mins of my "googling", and don't actually solve what the OP asked.