# How can I deploy a WAR file to Wildfly?

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly, war

In relation to [deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209847/262852) a `WAR` file to Wildfly, where should the [file be copied](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275780) to?

I don't see where the file is:

```
thufir@dur:~/java/wildfly$ 
thufir@dur:~/java/wildfly$ tree wildfly-17.0.0.Beta1  | grep wildflyMaps.war
│       └── wildflyMaps.war
thufir@dur:~/java/wildfly$
```

seems to be [exploded for](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275780) deployment:

> 6. Re: Can't see the .war after deploy ehugonnet Apprentice ehugonnet 21-Aug-2017 2:47 AM (in response to Claudio Miranda)
>
> During runtime the enabled war files are exploded by vfs in the tmp
>   directory. Those files will be deleted on stop / restart  / disable.
>
> The reference content is in the content data directory for recreating
>   the tmp files.

Comment: I assume you’re not deploying in standalone mode, so in domain mode you can’t copy a file for deployment, you’ll have to deploy via the cli or on the UI and the file gets saved as `content` under ~/data/content/<path_that_you_can_find_in_deployments_in_domain.xml>

Comment: is it possible from standalone mode, perhaps?

Comment: No standalone mode and domain mode are completely different. You can't have a scanner in domain mode so the 'only' solution is to use the management API with jboss-cli or the web-console.

Answer (score 7):

---

**Standalone mode**

---

The standard location for deployments in standalone mode is `Wildfly_Home/standalone/deployments` so you can copy your `war` to that folder via Java or any other means. It will deploy then upon starting the server. And actually it will auto-deploy even while Wildfly is running (and if not, just create a file and call it `wildflyMaps.war.dodeploy`).

---

**Domain mode**

---

With this, you can't just copy a `war` file to a directory. It can be done via the cli, but easier is to log on to the management console and go to the deployments section.

Once deployed, if you open up the `domain.xml`, you'll see something like this:

```
deployments
    deployment name="wildflyMaps.war" runtime-name="wildflyMaps.war"
             content sha1="d991471f79045413a7c63b8c2b5d4dc345be8808"/
        /deployment
/deployments
```

And using the above example, you'll find the deployed file at:

*Wildfly_Home/data/content/d9/91471f79045413a7c63b8c2b5d4dc345be8808*

and in there has a file called `content`. Copy that elsewhere and rename it as `anything.war` and you can open it and see that it is the `war` that you deployed.