# File element in parameter 'null' already exists: in Wildfly deployment

Tags: java, spring-mvc, wildfly, apache-commons, windows-server-2012

I have deployed my code on **Wildfly** app server. I am using **MultipartFile's transferTo()** to transfer the uploaded zip file to destination location.

```
MultipartFile.transferTo(File);
```

I am getting following exception :

```
File element in parameter 'null' already exists: 'E:\\\\JBoss\\wildfly-16.0.0_9090_9191\\\\standalone\\\\deployments\\\\MyWar.war\\\\My_Export.zip'
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.requireAbsent(FileUtils.java:2587)
at deployment.MyWar.war//org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2305)
at deployment.MyWar.war//org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2283)
at deployment.MyWar.war//org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:405)
at deployment.MyWar.war//org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:168)
```

As per the javadoc, if file already exists transferTo() will delete it. When I debug the code, *file.delete()* is returning 'true' and *file.exists()* is also returning 'true'.

**Note :** Above code is properly working on tomcat 8.5.

spring-web : 5.3.23

commons-io : 2.11

commons-fileupload : 1.4

Comment: Are you using an exploded WAR?

Comment: I performed normal steps to deploy the war.

Comment: There are several ways to deploy a WAR. Which steps did you use? Is the WAR a file or a directory?

Comment: exacting the war to standalone/deployment and starting it in standalone mode similar to step mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566970/how-can-i-deploy-a-war-file-to-wildfly

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a different directory? It could be that VFS is taking over which could result in strange things like this. You should try storing it outside of your deployment to a known path.

Comment: I do not have control over this. Also, not sure how VFS will play the role.

Comment: WildFly uses VFS for deployments. I'm somewhat guessing it could be at play here as I don't know how you resolve the path.